# Is there a way to show different colors using sns.barplot in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am looking for a solution , I want to add shades of blue for group '1' (light blue for Gender 'Male' dark blue for Gender'Female' )and shades of red for group '2'  (light red for Gender 'Male' dark red for Gender'Female' ) is there any possibility . I have tried color pallet also but was not able to set it. Can I get some helping hand . Thanks in Advance.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['percent'] = pd.Series([0.64, 0.36, 0.49, 0.51])
    df['gender'] = pd.Series(['M','F','M','F'])
    df['group'] =pd.Series([1,1,2,2])
    seaborn.barplot(x='group',y='percent',data=df, hue='gender')
```

[image]

Comment: If it's just 4 bars, it's fairly easy to modify the bars, even plot them manually.

Comment: @QuangHoang its just the sample of what I wanted. the number of groups differ hence then no of bars also changes accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ax` returned by `sns.barplot` will contain a bar container for each hue. Inside each container, there will be a bar for each of the groups.  To make sure Seaborn uses the same order for the x-values, the `order=` parameter can be set. Similar for the hue via the gender, the `hue_order` can be fixed.

Then, you can loop first through the containers, then through the individual bars to change their color. If there are more than 2 groups, more shades should be given (0 for very light, 1 for very dark). Similarly, more colormaps can be used if there were more hues.

As the legend doesn't fit anymore with the changed data, the code below removes it.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['percent'] = pd.Series([0.64, 0.36, 0.49, 0.51])
df['gender'] = pd.Series(['M', 'F', 'M', 'F'])
df['group'] = pd.Series([1, 1, 2, 2])
groups = np.unique(df['group'])
genders = ['M', 'F']
ax = sns.barplot(x='group', y='percent', data=df, order=groups, hue='gender', hue_order=genders)
for bar_container, shade in zip(ax.containers, [0.5, 0.9]):
    for bar, group_cmap in zip(bar_container, ['Reds', 'Blues']):
        bar.set_color(plt.get_cmap(group_cmap)(shade))
ax.legend_.remove()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I am not aware of containers. this made my work easier.